# Websphere decision center temp failed

Tags: websphere

I am trying to setup Websphere Decision center in my linux box, while creating cluster i'm getting below error, can you please some one help me on this

```
[10/6/20 6:05:19:477 UTC] 00000001 wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl createTempZipFileStrategyIfPossible Could not create temporary file using temporary location [ /opt/app/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/app-pprd-dmgr/wstemp/appdepl174fc8308c8 ]
[10/6/20 6:05:19:478 UTC] 00000001 wtp           E org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl createTempZipFileStrategyIfPossible Failed to create temporary file in system defined temporary location (java.io.tmpdir) [ /tmp ].
Failed to create temporary file.
A nested strategy will be used, but this usually slows performance dramatically.
[10/6/20 6:05:19:478 UTC] 00000001 wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl createNestedLoadStrategy Could not create temp file for base URI [ WEB-INF/lib/teamserver-ejb-8.10.0.0.jar ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a fix for this issue. Go and install depending on your version -[PM48503: Module update generates "Could not create temp file" warnings and runs slowly](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PM48503)

Answer (score 0):

Issue happened due to in-sufficient space in /tmp location, after increase space now my cluster is up and running